# MIPS Pipeline Stalls: SW after LW

Tags: mips, pipeline, cpu-architecture, forwarding

I am confused as to how a Store Word Instruction coming after an LW using the same $rt causes a pipeline stall in MIPS.
Consider this block of code:

```
  lw $s0,  0($t0)
  sw $s0, 12($t0)
  lw $s1,  4($t0)
  sw $s1, 16($t0)
  lw $s2,  8($t0)
  sw $s2, 20($t0)
```

Here 3 words are being shifted around in memory. For e.g in the first 2 lines, $s0 is loaded into ,
and then its contents are saved back in the memory. I'm not sure if the sw instruction required $s0 in EX stage or in MEM stage. if it is needed in MEM stage, wouldn't it be resolved just by forwarding without needing to stall the pipeline?

Comment: As harold points out, you could build hardware that can forward data from MEM->MEM, but it's usually easy to avoid writing code this inefficient.  MIPS has lots of registers which makes it easy to software-pipeline the loads, e.g. doing all 3 loads then all 3 stores.  On MIPS I (R2000), loads had a delay slot where it wasn't safe to use the result in the next instruction because the pipeline didn't even check for that hazard.  It's much more common to use just-loaded data with ALU instructions, not a store.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes I get that. I was entertaining a hypothetical scenario which was part of an assessment. Performing all loads and then saves is the simplest workaround

Comment: Sure, I was just pointing out why it's not worth spending transistors on in real hardware, even though it's possible.

Comment: Yes absolutely.

Answer (score 2):

Hypothetically, yes. Forwarding into the MEM stage directly would make it possible to execute dependent `LW` and `SW` back-to-back. As long as the loaded word is *stored* by the `SW` at least. It wouldn't be possible to have the `SW` use that loaded word as the base of the address without a pipeline bubble, otherwise it would require forwarding back in time.

But typically you would see a pipeline such as below (source: a model of a 5 stage pipelined MIPS in SIM-PL), with only one forwarder which feeds into EX. With a setup like that, there is no way to forward from `LW` into `SW`, the hardware required for it isn't there.

[image: MIPS pipeline]

Comment: Alright got it. So from a theoretical pov, if you want to resolve this by forwarding, you need to add multiplexors and an additional forwarding unit in the MEM stage of the pipeline?

Comment: @WaqasAhmad yes exactly

Comment: Right, Thanks! One last follow-up:  Would that be similar to the EX forwarding unit? Of course the inputs from the pipeline regs would change accordingly but the basic architecture would be containing inputs from pipelline registers and a mux somewhere in the mem stage?

Comment: @WaqasAhmad it would be similar, but actually a lot simpler because there is only one place to forward from (WB) instead of two

Comment: That's true! no need of two mux for twi alu inputs! Thanks a lot